# How to display status of vba macro on excel sheet?

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel VBA macro which does continuous updates of the database.

I trigger the macro using ActiveX Controls, "Start" button on the excel sheet.

I want to display the status as "**Working**" in one of the cells of the spreadsheet while it is working properly

In case of some error it should display "**Stopped Working**".

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put this in your button's OnClick method:

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Dim msgRange As Range
    ' change this to the cell you want to update
    Set msgRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
    msgRange.Value = "Working"

    ' your code goes here

    msgRange.Value = "Completed"
    Set msgRange = Nothing
    Exit Sub
    ErrorHandler:
        msgRange.Value = "Stopped working: " & Err.Description
        Set msgRange = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Use `Application.StatusBar` instead of some random cell! Otherwise this is a fine approach.

Comment: I've never been a big fan of `Application.StatusBar` as my users never expect to see anything meaningful at the bottom of the screen... I find it more obvious to put a status message right next to the button they've just clicked. But to each their own!

Answer (score 3):

or you can use Application.StatusBar which is the usual way of displaying updates:
`Application.StatusBar = "Updating..."`